# Running Unity development build in Android emulator without signing

Tags: unity, tools, debugging, build-process

I am working on project with a friend who uses Windows while I am using Ubuntu. We are using Unity collaborate and it's going fine except when we want to build.

The keystore is in his filesystem, `D:/Programs -Work/Game Dev/Keystore/user.keystore` and I can't replicate his path.

Also, when I try to do a development build and run, it fails because Unity says the apk isn't signed, contrary to this [article](https://answers.unity.com/questions/403985/building-for-android.html) which says that development builds do not need to be signed.

So this leads to two questions:

1. Is there any way to build from both devices?
2. Is there any way to emulate the game on android emulator?

Answer (score 1):

> Ans Q1:

Yes, you can build for both devices but you have to assign Keystore for each device or you could just disable the Custom Keystore option inside

> Player settings -> Publishing settings -> Custom Keystore -> Uncheck box. Like this:

**Warning:** If you uncheck custom Keystore then you would not be able to publish this APK to any store but of course, you could test it on your device. And later when you want to publish it then just Enable Custom Keystore and assign the Keystore you want to assign.

[image]

> Ans Q2:
>   Yes, you could emulate this on the Android emulator. like [Nox Player](https://www.bignox.com/). or Any other.